# Executors Lost while running Spark job on Yarn

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to process the partitioned Hive dataset consisting of more than 1000 columns via spark job.The issue I am facing is on increasing the number of records and running it over the yarn cluster, my executors gets lost one by one. I am trying to process around 5gb of data per partition.

```
spark-submit --class org.testJob.Trigger \
    ${MODULE_HOME}/lib/job.jar \
    --num-executors 17 --executor-cores 10  --driver-memory 52g \
    "${JSON_FILE}" \  
    --executor-memory 52g --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=3000
```

I am not sure if it the spark job tuning issue and also my job runs fine when run on less number of records.

Comment: We had similiar problems, it has definitely something to do with the Spark server and the memory that you allocate!

Comment: You are most likely experiencing OOMs, which are not fixed by changing the cluster configurations. You need to post the code for us to help you identify possible problems.